# Assigning variables in copying excel to excel file

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I'm trying to copy cells(1,1) of excel file 1 to cells(1,1) of excel file 2.
But assuming that I've placed the name of the file I want to open in cells(2,20) and I want to assign variable j = cells(2,20) and use it in a code in copying the file. I seem to be having problems with that.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Copy_Workbook()

j = Cells(2, 20)

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\GNPOWER\Desktop\TRADERS\Jonel\practice\data fetching\" & j & ".xlsx")

Workbooks("Practice_Copy_From.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = _
Workbooks(" & j & "&.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Am I missing something like a declaration or what?

I'm getting subscript of range 9 when running the program.

Comment: As a best practices you should place `Option Explicit` at that start of your module. This will force you to have to declare all your variables. This will help you on the long run to think about data types.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add an explicit quotation mark in the workbooks name declaration. Also there was an ampersand in front of the extension "&.xlsx" which I removed. Code would be:

```
Sub Copy_Workbook()

Dim j As String, wb As Workbook
j = Cells(2, 20).Value2
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\GNPOWER\Desktop\TRADERS\Jonel\practice\data fetching\" & j & ".xlsx")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need to open the "source" file

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Copy_Workbook()        
    Dim pathName As String, fileName As String

    fileName = Cells(2, 20).Value '<--| retrieve the file name from the currently active worksheet cell "A1"
    pathName = "C:\Users\GNPOWER\Desktop\TRADERS\Jonel\practice\data fetching\" '<--| set the folder path where "source" workbooks resides

    With Workbooks("Practice_Copy_From.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) '<--| reference your "target" cell
        .Value = "='" & pathName & "[" & fileName & "]Sheet1'!$A$1" '<--| write a formula that references the proper cell in the proper worksheet of the proper workbook
        .Value = .Value '<--| get rid of formula and leave value only
    End With
End Sub
```